# Animate DatePicker. Is possible?

Tags: iphone, ios, animation, view, uidatepicker

I would like to animate the entrance of a DatePicker.

Now, I show and remove the object whit this property:

```
datePicker.hidden=YES or
datePicker.hidden=NO
```

How can I animate the object like a View?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at block animations.

```
datePicker.alpha = 0.0f;
datePicker.hidden = NO;

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f animations:^{
    datePicker.alpha = 1.0f;
} completion:^(BOOL finished){}];
```

Comment: Also need datePicker.hidden = YES; after finishing animation.